# Make custom post type archive for administrator only

Tags: redirect, archives, permissions, wp-redirect

Simply I have made a custom post type named `ticket` and have created an `archive-ticket.php` file I want to make if the user that tries to visit the tickets archive page is not administrator redirect him/her to the home page.

I can make a simple solution like add something like this code in the file direct:

```
wp_redirect( home_url( '/' ) );
exit();
```

Buy i feel that this is not a profestional solution and feel that this is bad for seo.

Comment: Hi. What is your question then?

Comment: @HowardE What's the best solution to achieve what i need, Using the wp_redirect( home_url( '/' ) ); direct in the archive file is correct and not a poor solution or not?

Answer (score 0):

can you add this code in your `archive-ticket.php` before `get_header()`.

please check below snap for the same.

[image]

```
$user         = wp_get_current_user();
$roles        = (array) $user->roles;
$current_role = $roles[0];
$allowed_role = array('administrator');
if (!is_user_logged_in() || !in_array($current_role, $allowed_role)) {
    wp_redirect(site_url());
}
```

Thanks.